# How to get string terminated with new line in file handling using fscanf

Tags: c, file, scanf

I have these in my file:

```
JOS BUTTLER
JASON ROY
DAWID MALAN
JONNY BAISTROW
BEN STOKES
```

in different lines. And I want them to extract in my program to print them on the exact way they are in file. My imaginary output screen is:

```
JOS BUTTLER
JASON ROY
DAWID MALAN
JONNY BAISTROW
BEN STOKES
```

How would I do it using `fscanf()` and `printf()`. Moreover suggest me the way to change the delimiters of `fscanf()` to `\n`
I have tried something like this:

```
char n[5][30];
    printf("Name of 5 cricketers read from the file:\n");
   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   { 
            fscanf(fp,"%[^\n]s",&n[i]);
            printf("%s ",n[i]);         
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

But it works only for the first string and other string could not be displayed. There were garbage values.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT in your title - you can see the standard by looking at all the other questions on here.

Comment: Why do you insist on using `fscanf` when the correct tool for this job is `fgets`? In fact, you barely even need that. You can read one character at a time and echo them to the console.

Comment: okay but can you suggest me the way to change the delimiter of `scanf()` with strings

Comment: Change it to this: `fscanf(fp," %29[^\n]", n[i]);`. a) added space, b) length restriction, c) removed `s`, d) removed `&`. The leading space filters the previous newline left in the buffer. This is the way `fscanf` is intended to be used. It's horrible practice to kludge the newline away for at least 2 reasons: 1) there might be more then one whitespace in the input, and the leading space mentioned filters *any* amount of it, 2) the last line of a valid text file might not end with a newline.

Comment: @WeatherVane what actually the added space does? I didn't get it.

Comment: Some explanation: most of the format specifiers for `scanf` automatically filter leading whitespace, but `%c` and `%[]` and `%n` do not. Adding a space in front of the `%` instructs `scanf` to filter leading whitespace here too. The reason is that with those three specifiers allow you to read every character including whitespace, but a way is provided so they behave like `%d` and `%f` and `%s` where needed.

Comment: @paddy "'correct tool for this job is fgets" --> except when the name is at the limit of `n[]`.  Extra code needed to read a 29 character name into `n[]`.

Comment: @AnupAdhikari The reason we're recommending you use `fgets` is because `scanf` is a dead-end function.  `scanf` is barely okay for really, really simple input, but once you're trying to do anything at all complicated, `scanf` either can't do the job, or it's more trouble than it's worth.  Now, "reading a string with spaces" is one of the things that's, basically, too complicated for a reasonable use of `scanf`.  It can be done, but it's unnecessarily confusing, as evidenced by your (perfectly reasonable) question about what the mysterious extra space is for.

Comment: So please don't cling to `scanf` as if it's *the* way to do input.  It's not: there are better ways. When you're ready, please read [What can I use for input conversion instead of scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537)

Answer (score 1):

Be protected from buffer overflows limiting the length of the input, use `"%29[^\n]"` instead of `"%[^\n]s"` (you don't need the `s` specifier)

Consume the trailing new line (your wildcard `^\n` reads until a new line is found) using `%*c`, `*` means that a `char` will be read but won't be assigned:

```
fscanf(fp, "%29[^\n]%*c", n[i]);
```

or better yet (as pointed out by @WeatherVane), add a space before `%`, this will consume any blank space including tabs, spaces and new lines that may be left in the buffer from the previous read:

```
fscanf(fp, " %29[^\n]", n[i]);
```

Notice that you don't need an ampersand in `&n[i]`, `fscanf` wants a pointer but `n[i]` is already (decays into) a pointer when passed as an argument.

Finally, as pointed out by @paddy, `fgets` does all that for you and is a safer function, always prefer `fgets`.

Comment: THANK YOU, and what is the exact task of `%39` there?

Comment: 29 is the size of the array  -1 defined in `char n[5][30];` (39 was a typo, edited)

Comment: As `fgets()` reads and saves the `'\n'`, additional work needed to cope with longest name.

Answer (score 0):

> How to get string terminated with new line in file handling using fscanf

Use `fgets()` to read a *line* of input into a *string*.  It also reads and saves the line's `'\n'`.

Buffer size 30 may be too [small](https://www.crictracker.com/5-cricketers-with-the-longest-names/), consider 60.

To detect if the line is too long and lop off the `'\n'`, read in at least + 2 characters.

```
// char n[5][30];
#define NAME_N 5
#define NAME_SIZE 30
char n[NAME_N][NAME_SIZE]

char buf[NAME_SIZE + 2]
while (i < NAME_N && fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp) != NULL) {
  size_t len = strlen(buf);

  // Lop off potential trailing '\n'
  if (len > 0 && buf[len - 1] == '\n') {
    buf[--len] = '\0';
  }

  // Handle unusual name length
  if (len >= NAME_SIZE || len == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unacceptable name <%s>.\n", buf);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // Success
  strcpy(n[i], buf);
  printf("%s\n", n[i]); 
  i++;
}
```